# How to configure IP/listeners in Apache Kafka so that external clients can connect to it

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I need to use the ip of kafka for my other microservices. but when am deploying by this method theres no external IP moreover when am trying with localhost everything is working fine. so can anyone help me in understanding how to set up the ext IP of lb for the Kafka here to use it in

Answer (score 2):

You just need to configure advertised listeners so that external clients can connect.

To do so, you need to configure `advertised.listeners` inside `server.properties`:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your-kafka-host-1:9092,PLAINTEXT://your-kafka-host-1:9093,PLAINTEXT://your-kafka-host-2:9092,...
```

---

Alternatively, if you are using Docker images, you simply need to export `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka can be installed as *LoadBalancer External Service Type* on kubernetes using helm. Steps are [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka#loadbalancer-external-service-type). Following is needed in helm's `values.yaml` to do it:

```
 external:
  enabled: true
  type: LoadBalancer
   ...
  "advertised.listeners": |-
    EXTERNAL://${LOAD_BALANCER_IP}:31090
  "listener.security.protocol.map": |-
    PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
```

Kafka installed as LoadBalancer External Service Type:

```
$ kubectl -n kafka get svc
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
kafka                      ClusterIP      10.39.241.217   <none>           9092/TCP                     2m39s
kafka-0-external           LoadBalancer   10.39.242.45    35.200.238.174   31090:30108/TCP              2m39s
kafka-1-external           LoadBalancer   10.39.241.90    35.244.44.162    31090:30582/TCP              2m39s
kafka-2-external           LoadBalancer   10.39.243.160   35.200.149.80    31090:30539/TCP
```

Now, to connect external clients to kafka, deploy kubernetes ingress in front of this kafka service using following links:

- [k8s ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)
- [k8s nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)
- [kafka-manager helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/kafka-manager)

Comment: I was using this https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka, in this i tried to configure kafka as a load balancer but it was not working as expected.